# How to test a function returned by a custom hook that calls useReducer dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

For our API calls we have a custom hook named `useApi` that returns 5 functions (get, post, put, patch, del) and each of those functions has endpoint, success, fail as parameters. post, put, patch additionally have a body parameter.

useApi.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import * as api from "../../services/api";
import { GlobalContext } from "../../contexts/context";

export const useApi = () => {
    const context = useContext(GlobalContext);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const get = async ({ endpoint, success, fail }) => {
        if (loading)
            return;

        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const result = await api.get("", endpoint, context);
            context.dispatch({ type: success, result });
            return result || {};
        } catch (err) {
            context.dispatch({ dispatch: fail, err });
            return {
                error: true,
                message: err,
            };
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    ... cut some stuff here to shorten

    return {
        loading,
        get,
        post,
        put,
        patch,
        del,
    };
};
```

The idea being, we use this custom hook in our functional components to interact with our API and dispatch an action depending on the outcome of the API call.

Example.js

```
const Example = () => {
    const { examples } = useContext(GlobalContext);
    const { loading, get } = useApi();

    const listExamples = async () => {
        await get({
            endpoint: '/example',
            success: 'LIST_EXAMPLES',
            fail: 'LIST_EXAMPLES_FAILED'
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        listExamples();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Page
            title="Examples"
        >
            {
                !loading && examples.map(example => (<h1>{example}</h1>))

            }
            {
                loading &&
                <ProgressSpinner message={'Loading Workflows...'}/>
            }
        </Page>
    );
};

export default Example;
```

We are now trying to implement tests around this and I'm unsure of how to approach it. I'm able to render my component and ensure the list of items contains data I'm expecting (using dummy data), but it's still using the actual API calls. I'm not sure how to mock in something that can check to see if the function returned by the custom hook is called and I'm unsure of how to mock the global state change when that function is called as well.

```
import React from 'react';
import { GlobalContext } from '../../contexts/context';
import init from '../../__tools__/contextSetup';
import ExampleList from '../../pages/Example/ExampleList/ExampleList';
import { render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { light } from "../../theme";

const example = {
    details: {
        description: 'Test Example 1 - Description',
        id: 'testingExample1',
        name: 'Test Example 1',
    },
    list: {
        data: [
            {
                description: 'Test Example 1 - Description',
                id: 'testingExample1',
                name: 'Test Example 1',
            },
        ],
        values: [
            {
                description: 'Test Example 1 - Description',
                id: 'testingExample1',
                name: 'Test Example 1',
            },
        ],
    }
};

describe('Example List', () => {
    it('loads the example list on mount', async () => {
        const dispatch = jest.fn();
        const state = { ...init };

        let ui;

        await act(async () => {
            ui = await render(
                <GlobalContext.Provider
                    value={{
                        ...state,
                        dispatch
                    }}
                >
                    <ThemeProvider theme={light}>
                        <ExampleList/>
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </GlobalContext.Provider>
            )
        });

        expect(await screen.getByText('There\'s nothing here...')).toBeInTheDocument();

        await (act(async () => {
            await ui.rerender(
                <GlobalContext.Provider
                    value={{
                        ...state,
                        dispatch,
                        example,
                    }}
                >
                    <ThemeProvider theme={light}>
                        <ExampleList/>
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </GlobalContext.Provider>
            )
        }));

        expect(await screen.getByText('Test Example 1')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
})
```

Comment: Your whole REST-like approach aside, have you considered mocking the `useApi.js` module, so it returns a custom (non-API calling) version during testing?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how to implement it. It gets called automaticlly by the useEffect and I'm not sure how to intercept the call to the API and then ensure the state is updated.

Comment: Well, assuming you can mock `useApi.js`, you can make the hook return whatever you want. Instead of the real `get`, you'd return a version that e.g. waits a second then acts as if it just got the dummy data from the API call. How to do that depends on how your real hook is implemented. You can simply copy it and replace all actual API calls with "wait a bit then inject dummy data" as a simple approach.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I've got a very similar situation I'd like to test